# Join polygon footprint to a dataset that contains the central points of buildings

Tags: polygon, openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I have polygon information of all buildings in a city in file geodatabase format (`.gdb`). I have another dataset stored in CSV format that contains latitude and longitude information on the centers of buildings. Using QGIS/Python, how is it possible to attach the building polygon footprint to these central points?

**Sample of data after the comments:**

The below table, shows a CSV file of buildings and the features exist in this table. For all buildings, I have the LATITUDE and LONGITUDE information.
[image]

I have a completely different dataset that includes all the building geometry. This file geodatabase table contains the below attributes:
[image]
[image]

I am looking for some ways to match the center points of buildings to the second dataset to add geometry shape of buildings to this central points and export the file as a .csv format. The results should be look like the below:
[image]

How is it possible to do so?

Comment: If your data share a primary and secondary key you could join on those keys.  It sounds like your CSV has locations only but I am not sure unless you post some screen shots of your tables.  Plot the CSV in QGIS then use spatial joint to connect the attribute data.

Comment: Do you mean `.gdb` (file geodatabase) format? Do you mean "surroundings"?

Comment: @GBG I am not sure if I could find any keys for these two datasets as they are both for one city, but has two different data provider. I have edited the question to add more details and samples of the data. In QGIS, I have used VECTORE--> Data Management Tools--> Join attributes by location. It gives me some results but I am not sure if this is the right way and if I can add a column to the results section that gives me the central points of buildings with a column called geometry that has values like Polygone ((....)) [dave as the last photo I uploaded)

Comment: @Vince, I have edited the post. Thanks

Comment: You're still asking two questions here. "Is it possible?" isn't the right question, since the inevitable "Yes" is of little use. What you really want to know is, "How is it possible...?" Therefore the OSM question is a distraction.

Comment: @Vince thanks for the suggestion of making it more clear, I removed the OSM part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  From your posting and the fact that you have different data sources with no primary and secondary keys in those data to join tables your best solution is a spatial join.

1. Convert your CSV files to point data.  [See this tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html) for help.
2. [See this tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html) for getting help with the spatial join.